# Adding HTML to Javascript IF function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to edit a script so that I can format the output using HTML but unsure how to properly format it. At the moment the script is as below, but what I would like to achieve is as per the second script below. I know that the second script doesn't make sense but I'm just trying to show what I'd basically like to achieve, but not sure how to go about achieving it. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

**Original script:**

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
timber.productPage({
  money_format: "{{ shop.money_format }}",
  variant: variant,
  selector: selector
});
if (variant) {
    if (variant.inventory_management == "shopify" && variant.inventory_policy != "continue") {
    if (variant.inventory_quantity > 0) {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text('We have ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' in stock.');
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("This product is sold out");
    }
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("In stock - order now");
    }
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("");
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
timber.productPage({
  money_format: "{{ shop.money_format }}",
  variant: variant,
  selector: selector
});
if (variant) {
    if (variant.inventory_management == "shopify" && variant.inventory_policy != "continue") {
    if (variant.inventory_quantity > 0) {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text('<div class="stock">We have ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' in stock.</div>');
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("<div class="sold-out">This product is sold out</div> - <a href="link">contact us</a>");
    }
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("<div class="in-stock">In stock</div> - order now");
    }
    } else {
    jQuery('#variant-inventory').text("");
    }
};
```

Comment: notice the syntax highlighting and how it starts breaking around the quotes you're attempting to use in strings. You need to escape quotes within strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `.text()` use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
jQuery('#variant-inventory').html('<div class="stock">We have ' + variant.inventory_quantity + ' in stock.</div>');
```

`.text()` is just a simpler way to do `Element.textContent||Element.innerText||...etc =` which alters the complete  content with a (`nodeType`**3**) string, *"printing"* tag-characters literally > <  .
`.html()` on the other hand  is a jQuery method that uses JS's `Element.innerHTML` which actually inserts HTML-like strings making them actual DOM nodes.

---

Watch out for **quotes**!!! This is incorrect:

```
"<div class="sold-out">This product is sold out</div> - <a href="link">contact us</a>"
```

should be:

```
'<div class="sold-out">This product is sold out</div> - <a href="link">contact us</a>'
```

just like you did a couple of lines above...

---

<sub>***Tip-of-the-day***:</sub>

Take care of your fingers! Don't write all over the place `jQuery`, instead wrap it into a shorthand DOM ready which encapsulates the `$` alias securely:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {                          // DOM ready and $ alias secured in scope

  // Your DOM ready code here.
  // Now you're free to use the $ alias and save some bites and finger nails
  $('#variant-inventory').html("YEY!!");

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Roko. Things like this seem straightforward once they're explained, but trying to remember them in the first place is a big learning curve for me! Thanks for all the information, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.html() instead of jQuery.text()